# Can the "migrated from StackOverflow" notice expire, please?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

There are questions that were migrated from other sites, e.g. Stack Overflow.

These questions have a migration notice, e.g. [Remove audio from video file with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg)

[image: Migration notice]

<sub>(Sorry, I didn't know where to put the red freehand circles, because the whole image is the notice itself).</sub>

Now, such a notice may be helpful in the beginning, directly after migration. We then know that the question might not obey the rules of our site yet. However, after some time, the question should either be accepted as a valid question or it should be closed.

After 8 years, I personally don't care any longer where the question came from. So maybe we could remove the unnecessary clutter. It does not provide additional benefit any longer and just makes the site less usable.

I think 3 months of a notice should be enough.

Comment: Eh, how does it matter? There's really no disadvantage to it, and if you use an ad blocker, you can easily block the notice.

Comment: Moderators can clear migration histories, so if you spot one that you *really* think is unnecessary, flag for a moderator to clear the migration history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309916/the-question-migration-notice-should-be-hidden-after-a-certain-time-threshold) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299180/hide-notice-for-migrated-questions-after-30-days) more than once on Meta StackExchange. The proposals for this on SE Meta gained extremely little notice or traction.

This would be considered a "core site function", because *every* StackExchange site implements this, not just Super User. It's a *Good Thing* to have different StackExchange sites behave consistently, so that users can seamlessly move from one community to the next without being surprised by differences in the user experience. Also, the SE developers don't have enough time in their day to maintain completely separate codebases for every different SE site, especially since Area51 was created and the explosion of hundreds of sub-sites. The preference is definitely towards giving each site a visual *theme* but with identical logic for all the behavior. The only exception is little easter eggs and such.

In my experience, the Stack Exchange developers will *basically never* implement a change to a core site function just for one specific Stack Exchange site, except in extremely rare cases where the site in question is StackOverflow or Meta StackOverflow, due to the sometimes unique needs of programmers and the fact that StackOverflow is, by far, the highest-traffic site on the network. Super User is definitely not a large enough site to get even highly popular changes implemented "just for us" in a way that differs from the rest of the network.

Basically, you're barking up the wrong tree. The most you can do is upvote the posts proposing this on Meta StackExchange and hope that it gets implemented network-wide at some point.

Comment: I didn't search on Meta.SE. Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t support the OP’s proposal.  (I don’t really object to it either; I basically just don’t care.)  But I don’t see how it’s a site-specific proposal.  If a question was posted on site ε, and it got migrated to site ω, and after six to eight weeks (or three months) it hasn’t been closed, why do we need to continue to display the migration history *on the question itself?*  We have revision history and timeline for things like that.  P.S. Are there Easter eggs on Stack Exchange?